# How to get selected radio button tag using listview

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I have created a radio button in my fragment and now trying to find an `eventListener` which I can use to get radio button id/tag when user selects radio button. Here is my layout:

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/zone_types_list_View"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/room_type_border"/>
    </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

In fragment:

```
 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     listView = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.zone_types_list_View);
     ..
     ..
 }


private void addRadioButtons(final List<String> zoneTypesList) {
    if (getActivity() != null) {
        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                radioGroup = new RadioGroup(mActivity);
                List<RadioButton> radioButtonsList = new ArrayList<RadioButton>();
                for (String ss : zoneTypesList) {
                    radioButton = new RadioButton(mActivity);
                    radioButton.setText(ss);
                    radioButton.setTag(ss.trim());

                    radioButtonsList.add(radioButton);
                    radioGroup.addView(radioButton);
                 }
                 listView.addView(radioGroup);
             }
        });
    }
}
```

I am using `addRadioButtons(List<String>)` to add dynamically radio button on view. Can someone tell me which component should used to listener a event when radio button select and possible to get the radio button tag instead of only position or Id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener.html):

```
radioButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        String tag = (String) buttonView.getTag();
    }
});
```